# Batch - how to create multiple text files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following script:

```
@echo off

:metka

SET /p LPN=[Please scan/add LPN-nr.]
SET /p NumberOfBoxes=[Please add number of boxes/quantity]

echo %LPN%
echo %NumberOfBoxes%

if %LPN%==0 (goto:metka)

pause
```

Question:
how can I extend the script with the following use cases?

Use case 1:

If %NumberOfBoxes% is less than 2, then create the following text file (where %LPN% is 123):

1. LPN123.TXT (contents LPN123)

Use case 2:

If %NumberOfBoxes% is greater than or equal to 2, then create as many text files as specified in %NumberOfBoxes% like so (where %LPN% is 123):

1. LPN123.TXT (contents LPN123)
2. LPN123-2.TXT (contents LPN123-2)
3. LPN123-3.TXT (contents LPN123-3)
4. LPN123-4.TXT (contents LPN123-4)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a `for` loop:

```
@echo off

:metka

SET /p LPN=[Please scan/add LPN-nr.]
SET /p NumberOfBoxes=[Please add number of boxes/quantity]

echo %LPN%
echo %NumberOfBoxes%

if %LPN%==0 goto metka

echo LPN%LPN% > LPN%LPN%.TXT

for /l %%i in (2, 1, %NumberOfBoxes%) do (
    echo LPN%LPN%-%%i > LPN%LPN%-%%i.TXT
)

pause
```

Comment: If I got it right, the command `echo LPN%LPN% > LPN%LPN%.TXT` becomes executed twice when `%NumberOfBoxes` equals `1`, so to prevent that you could: 1. (preferred) change `for /l %%i in (1, 1, %NumberOfBoxes%) do` to `for /l %%i in (2, 1, %NumberOfBoxes%) do`, remove the `if` condition in the loop body and just keep `echo LPN%LPN%-%%i > LPN%LPN%-%%i.TXT`; 2. change `if %NumberOfBoxes% lss 2` to `if %NumberOfBoxes% lss 1`…

Comment: Furthermore, you should do `set NumberOfBoxes=` just before `set /P NumberOfBoxes=` (same for `LPN`) in order to avoid usage of the previous value in case the user just presses *{Enter}* in the prompt. Since both prompted values seem to be purely numeric, you should do `set /A NumberOfBoxes+=0` just after `set /P NumberOfBoxes=` (same for `LPN`, if it is a number too), which forces conversion to a valid 32-bit signed integer (empty or invalid numeric input becomes `0`), so you do not run into troubles when expanding `%NumberOfBoxes%` (and `%LPN%`) later…

Comment: Finally, for numeric (32-bit signed integer) equality checks you could use `if %%i equ 1` instead of `if %%i==1`…

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. You are correct in that the command `echo LPN%LPN% > LPN%LPN%.TXT` gets executed twice if `%NumberOfBoxes%` is 1, and I like your first solution to that problem.  I'll add that to my answer, thank you! As far as your second comment, The question asked how to extend the script, so I left everything the OP already had in there. Maybe they want `%NumberOfBoxes%` and `%LPN%` to carry over from the previous loop if nothing is entered, and maybe they want it to crash if a non-numerical value is entered.

Comment: first of all many thanks for a quick answer.

Question:
each file created should have fixed text before and after the contents of the variable %LPN%.

How can I implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No problem!  You can just add your text to the `echo` statement.  If you look at the line `echo LPN%LPN%-%%i > LPN%LPN%-%%i.TXT`, you can just add in more text around `%LPN%`.  For example, `echo LPNMoreText%LPN%MoreText-%%i > LPN%LPN%-%%i.TXT`